# localize pandas datetime during daylight saving with multiple notations

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timezone, dst

I have pandas DataFrames with time-series that cover middle european daylight saving time disturbances each spring and autum for a few years.
For some dfs, everything works as expected using `dt.tz_localize` but I have troubles solving the following time notation:

```
not_working = pd.to_datetime(
    pd.Series(
        [
            "2017-10-29 01:45:00",
            "2017-10-29 02:00:00",
            "2017-10-29 02:15:00",
            "2017-10-29 02:45:00",
            "2017-10-29 03:00:00",
            "2017-10-29 02:15:00",
            "2017-10-29 02:45:00",
            "2017-10-29 03:00:00",
        ]
    )
)
not_working = not_working.dt.tz_localize(tz="Europe/Berlin", ambiguous="infer")
```

which results in this error message:

```
pytz.exceptions.AmbiguousTimeError: 2017-10-29 02:00:00
```

When localizing 02:00 twice instead, it works as expected. Sadly, I can't control the input data format. Thus, I am wondering how to localize my data above.

```
working = pd.to_datetime(
pd.Series(
    [
        "2017-10-29 01:45:00",
        "2017-10-29 02:00:00",
        "2017-10-29 02:15:00",
        "2017-10-29 02:45:00",
        "2017-10-29 02:00:00",
        "2017-10-29 02:15:00",
        "2017-10-29 02:45:00",
        "2017-10-29 03:00:00",
        ]
    )
)

working = working.dt.tz_localize(tz="Europe/Berlin", ambiguous="infer")
```

This fix works, but I'd prefer a less hacky solution. The `nonexisting` parameter does not work together with `ambigous` as I don't want to build a boolean array first.

```
not_working = not_working - pd.Timedelta(seconds=1)
not_working = not_working.dt.tz_localize(tz="Europe/Berlin", ambiguous="infer")
not_working = not_working + pd.Timedelta(seconds=1)
```

Comment: how regular are the time intervals between the elements (timestamps) of your input? depending on that, an idea would be to determine a boolean mask that specifies DST active or not "manually". You can then feed that mask to the ambiguous keyword. (btw. this is not specific to pytz so I removed the tag).

Comment: In my case always 15 minutes between each timestamp. I'd prefer not to calculate the dst-change-day and "manually" build an array based on it, but maybe I don't understand your suggestion yet :)

Comment: actually, I think the ambiguous time error is not the only problem here; in the example `"2017-10-29 03:00:00"` appears twice, which means you have a duplicate timestamp (UTC offset would resolve to +01:00 in both cases). So I'm not sure anymore my suggestion above would be a viable solution...

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're starting with datetime data that's not *time-zone aware* and so `tz_localize` is not able to resolve ambiguities for some special dates/times related to daylight savings.

If you make your dataframe data time-zone aware to begin with by using the option [`utc=True`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas-to-datetime), you can convert it to the desired time zone:

```
working = pd.to_datetime(
    pd.Series(
        [
            "2017-10-29 01:45:00",
            "2017-10-29 02:00:00",
            "2017-10-29 02:15:00",
            "2017-10-29 02:45:00",
            "2017-10-29 03:00:00",
            "2017-10-29 02:15:00",
            "2017-10-29 02:45:00",
            "2017-10-29 03:00:00",
        ]
    ),
    utc=True
)

working.dtypes
# datetime64[ns, UTC]

working.dt.tz_convert(tz="Europe/Berlin")
# 0   2017-10-29 02:45:00+01:00
# 1   2017-10-29 03:00:00+01:00
# 2   2017-10-29 03:15:00+01:00
# 3   2017-10-29 03:45:00+01:00
# 4   2017-10-29 04:00:00+01:00
# 5   2017-10-29 03:15:00+01:00
# 6   2017-10-29 03:45:00+01:00
# 7   2017-10-29 04:00:00+01:00
```

If the original data are not in the UTC time zone you can adjust them before converting adding or subtracting the appropriate time interval

```
working = working-pd.Timedelta('01:00:00')

working.dt.tz_convert(tz="Europe/Berlin")
# 0   2017-10-29 02:45:00+02:00
# 1   2017-10-29 02:00:00+01:00
# 2   2017-10-29 02:15:00+01:00
# 3   2017-10-29 02:45:00+01:00
# 4   2017-10-29 03:00:00+01:00
# 5   2017-10-29 02:15:00+01:00
# 6   2017-10-29 02:45:00+01:00
# 7   2017-10-29 03:00:00+01:00
# dtype: datetime64[ns, Europe/Berlin]
```

Comment: the OP uses tz_localize, not tz_convert as the input is local time, not UTC

Comment: @FObersteiner is right. Sadly, my input data is fixed to be non-aware.